# Failure to add keys to map in parallel

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
  var res: GenMap[Point, GenSeq[Point]] = points.par.groupBy(point => findClosest(point, means))
  means.par.foreach(mean => if(!res.contains(mean)) {
    println("Map doesn't contain mean: " + mean)
    res += mean -> GenSeq.empty[Point]
    println("Map contains?: " + res.contains(mean))
  })
```

That uses this case class:

```
case class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double, val z: Double)
```

Basically, the code groups the `Point` elements in `points` around the `Point` elements in `means`. The algorithm itself is not very important though.

My problem is that I am getting the following output:

```
Map doesn't contain mean: (0.44, 0.59, 0.73)
Map doesn't contain mean: (0.44, 0.59, 0.73)
Map doesn't contain mean: (0.1, 0.11, 0.11)
Map doesn't contain mean: (0.1, 0.11, 0.11)
Map contains?: true
Map contains?: true
Map contains?: false
Map contains?: true
```

Why would I ever get this?

```
Map contains?: false
```

I am checking if a key is in the `res` map. If it is not, then I'm adding it.
So how can it not be present in the map?

Is there an issue with parallelism?

Comment: Does the issue happen without using parallelization?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a race condition in line

```
res += mean -> GenSeq.empty[Point]
```

more than one thread is reasigning res concurrently so some entries can be missed.

This code solves the problem:

```
val closest = points.par.groupBy(point => findClosest(point, means))
val res = means.foldLeft(closest) {
  case (map, mean) =>
    if(map.contains(mean))
      map
    else
      map + (mean -> GenSeq.empty[Point])
}
```

Comment: You are right, the second part is not executed in parallel. I assumed that the computationally expensive part was the execution of findClosest() function. This is a simple solution that should be quite efficient in terms of parallelism (althought it can be improved). I think that if 'means' is not really big it will be as efficient (if not better) as it is than with a parallel solution, you have to think that there's always an overhead when you create parallel programs and sometimes it's not worth to parallelize some parts of the execution

Answer (score 0):

Processing a point changes means and the result is sensitive to processing order, so the algorithm doesn't lend itself to parallel execution. If parallel execution is important enough to allow a change of algorithm, then it might be possible to find an algorithm that can be applied in parallel.

Using a known set of grouping points, such as grid square centres, means that the points can be allocated to their grouping points in parallel and grouped by their grouping points in parallel:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.parallel.ParMap
import scala.collection.{GenMap, GenSeq, Map}
import scala.math._
import scala.util.Random

class ParallelPoint {
  val rng = new Random(0)

  val groups: Map[Point, Point] = (for {
                i <- 0 to 100
                j <- 0 to 100
                k <- 0 to 100
              }
              yield {
                val p = Point(10.0 * i, 10.0 * j, 10.0 * k)
                p -> p
              }
    ).toMap

  val points: Array[Point] = (1 to 10000000).map(aaa => Point(rng.nextDouble() * 1000.0, rng.nextDouble() * 1000.0, rng.nextDouble() * 1000.0)).toArray

  def findClosest(point: Point, groups: GenMap[Point, Point]): (Point, Point) = {
    val x: Double = rint(point.x / 10.0) * 10.0
    val y: Double = rint(point.y / 10.0) * 10.0
    val z: Double = rint(point.z / 10.0) * 10.0

    val mean: Point = groups(Point(x, y, z)) //.getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"$point out of range of mean ($x, $y, $z).") )

    (mean, point)
  }

  @tailrec
  private def total(points: GenSeq[Point]): Option[Point] = {
    points.size match {
      case 0 => None
      case 1 => Some(points(0))
      case _ => total((points(0) + points(1)) +: points.drop(2))
    }
  }

  def mean(points: GenSeq[Point]): Option[Point] = {
    total(points) match {
      case None => None
      case Some(p) => Some(p / points.size)
    }
  }

  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println("starting test ...")

  val res: ParMap[Point, GenSeq[Point]] = points.par.map(p => findClosest(p, groups)).groupBy(pp => pp._1).map(kv => kv._1 -> kv._2.map(v => v._2))

  val groupTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  println(s"... grouped result after ${groupTime - startTime}ms ...")

  points.par.foreach(p => if (! res(findClosest(p, groups)._1).exists(_ == p)) println(s"point $p not found"))

  val checkTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println(s"... checked grouped result after ${checkTime - startTime}ms ...")

  val means: ParMap[Point, GenSeq[Point]] = res.map{ kv => mean(kv._2).get -> kv._2 }

  val meansTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println(s"... means calculated after ${meansTime - startTime}ms.")
}

object ParallelPoint {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = new ParallelPoint()
}

case class Point(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  def +(that: Point): Point = {
      Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y, this.z + that.z)
  }

  def /(scale: Double): Point = Point(x/ scale, y / scale, z / scale)
}
```

The last step replaces the grouping point with the calculated mean of the grouped points as the map key. This processes 10 million points in about 30 seconds on my 2011 MBP.